# Get best combination from a set of Array containing items

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations, knapsack-problem

I have a set of array of elements like bellow:

1. A [8] = [1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 ] meter
2. B [5] = [5  5  5  5  5 ] meter
3. C [7] = [0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ] meter

I want to get best combination of items from above container.

For example to get 7 meter size

- Option 1 : from A we can take 7 item ( 1+1+1+1+1+1+1)
- Option 2 : from B we can take 1 item and from A we can take 2 (5 + (1 + 1))
- Option 3 : from B we can take 1 item and from C we can take 4 (5 + (.5*4))
- Option 4 : from B we can take 1 item, from B take 1 and from C we can take 2 (5 + 1 + (.5*2))

Let me know how I can solve this. I have tried with knapsack but struggling to get the best combination.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is your question? Get *all* or *the best* combination?

Comment: If you want the 'Best' combination, explain what best means in this problem.
If it is simple all possible combiations, just put 3 nested loops.

Comment: it can be easily solved using subset sum problem.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I have edited my question. Is that enough to get an idea about  the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've written this simple method for you, including the `Resource` class that's been used for the provided example.

```
private static class Resource {
      private double value;
      private int available;

          public Resource(double value, int available) {
             this.value = value;
             this.available = available;
          }

          public void setValue(double value) {
             this.value = value;
          }

          public double getValue() {
             return this.value;
          }

          public void setAvailable(int available) {
             this.available = available;
          }

          public int getAvailable() {
             return this.available;
          }
       }
```

Method that prints the numbers on screen

```
public static void findNumbers(Resource[] availableResources, double targetNumber) {
      // Keeps Track of which resource is currently in use.
      int resourceInCheck = 0;
      // Remainder of the wanted number
      double remainder = targetNumber;

      System.out.print("Values: ");
      while(remainder > 0) {
         if(remainder >= availableResources[resourceInCheck].getValue() && availableResources[resourceInCheck].getAvailable() > 0) {

            System.out.print(availableResources[resourceInCheck].getValue() + ", ");

            remainder -= availableResources[resourceInCheck].getValue();

            availableResources[resourceInCheck].setAvailable( (availableResources[resourceInCheck].getAvailable() - 1) );
         }
         else {
            resourceInCheck++;
         }
      }
   }
```

Main Method

```
public static void main(String[] args){

      Resource firstResource = new Resource(5, 5);
      Resource secondResource = new Resource(1, 8);
      Resource thirdResource = new Resource(0.5, 7);

      Resource[] availableResources = {firstResource, secondResource, thirdResource};

      findNumbers(availableResources, 17.5);
   }
```

Output

```
Values: 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5,
```

Again, this is a possible solution to fit the characteristics of this problem, and obviously there are other ways to tackle it.

**Note:** `targetNumber` should be `<=` than the sum of all available resources.

**Note2:** Array of Resources needs to be sorted from larger to smaller value.

Comment: Thank you for the solution but the resource needs to be in sorted order. If you just change the resource order the result changed.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I figured it is not hard to sort an array of Resources, and also, depending on your needs there are many ways to do so, rendering me  providing such method off topic. However, yes you're right, I'll add this as a second Note for clarity cause in my head it was obvious but that alone is never useful!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be simplest, and most clear, to just generate all possible combinations and calculate & compare against the desired total?

Something like this:

```
:For A :In 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    :For B :In 0 1 2 3 4 5
        :For C :In 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
            :If (7 == (A * 1) + (B * 5) + (C * 0.5))
                [append to list of results]
           :End
       :End
    :End
:End
```

Then you get these results to pick from (total = 7 meters):

```
┌───┬───┬─────┐
│1 m│5 m│0.5 m│
├───┼───┼─────┤
│0  │1  │4    │
├───┼───┼─────┤
│1  │1  │2    │
├───┼───┼─────┤
│2  │1  │0    │
├───┼───┼─────┤
│4  │0  │6    │
├───┼───┼─────┤
│5  │0  │4    │
├───┼───┼─────┤
│6  │0  │2    │
├───┼───┼─────┤
│7  │0  │0    │
└───┴───┴─────┘
```

For the 17.5 meter case:

```
┌───┬───┬─────┐
│1 m│5 m│0.5 m│
├───┼───┼─────┤
│0  │3  │5    │
├───┼───┼─────┤
│1  │3  │3    │
├───┼───┼─────┤
│2  │3  │1    │
├───┼───┼─────┤
│4  │2  │7    │
├───┼───┼─────┤
│5  │2  │5    │
├───┼───┼─────┤
│6  │2  │3    │
├───┼───┼─────┤
│7  │2  │1    │
└───┴───┴─────┘
```

And along the way, you can resolve all possible unique total lengths (no big surprises there :-)):

```
┌─┬───┬─┬───┬─┬───┬─┬───┬─┬───┬─┬───┬─┬───┬─┬───┬─┬───┬─┬───┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┬──┬────┐
│0│0.5│1│1.5│2│2.5│3│3.5│4│4.5│5│5.5│6│6.5│7│7.5│8│8.5│9│9.5│10│10.5│11│11.5│12│12.5│13│13.5│14│14.5│15│15.5│16│16.5│17│17.5│18│18.5│19│19.5│20│20.5│21│21.5│22│22.5│23│23.5│24│24.5│25│25.5│26│26.5│27│27.5│28│28.5│29│29.5│30│30.5│31│31.5│32│32.5│33│33.5│34│34.5│35│35.5│36│36.5│
└─┴───┴─┴───┴─┴───┴─┴───┴─┴───┴─┴───┴─┴───┴─┴───┴─┴───┴─┴───┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┴──┴────┘
```